# ODBC ERROR Details [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server] Communication link failure with database. Trying [1] to reconnect the link

Tags: sql-server, tcp

SQL server 2005 and application written in C.

I have done the below things to try to resolve the error but I'm still facing the issue.

- Disable TCP Chimney Features in OS Level (app\db server).
- Disable TCP Chimney and Offload features in the properties of NIC card (DB server).
- Disable:

  - IPv4 Checksum Offload
  - IPv4 Large Send Offload
  - Receive Side Scaling
- Disable TCP Chimney and Offload features in the properties of NIC card (app server).
- Disable:

  - Offload Receive IP Checksum
  - Offload Receive TCP Checksum
  - Offload Transmit IP Checksum
  - Offload Transmit TCP Checksum
  - Offload TCP Segmentation

Any ideas what else it can be?

Comment: Why did you start digging into by default very sensible TCP/IP stack settings? Can you explain the situation somewhat better? Where is the client, where is the database, do other connection attempts (e.g. with SQL Server Management Studio) succeed? Can you ping the machine? Can you access SQL Server's port using for example telnet? And so on.

Comment: application and database servers are different, but lying in same DC. I am able to connect with database. Multiple applications of same nature are running but getting issue in 2 applications (error comes 5-6 times a day and during that time my application stuck and need restart). there is no drop in ping.

Comment: Please [edit] that additional but very relevant information into your question. Some information about the workload would be very welcome as well as versions of servers and drivers.